# same session value exists among different users

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing and intranet web application. In Global.asax file's session_start event I get the domain identity using user.idenity and put it into session value. Now I have a master page where I am accession that session value to show the user name.

I am using windows authentication and identity impersonation true. But after publishing it the user name who first logins in the system gets displayed to everyone.

I am not able to find out the cause. Please suggest.

Comment: Show your code to put and retrieve the value that gets corrupted.

Comment: Also you should read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80538/how-to-ask-questions-on-stack-overflow

Comment: Can't you get it directly from `Page.User.Identity.Name`? Why do you need to store it in the Session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to determine the problem without some sample code, but I can guess what's happening.

Are you understanding that opening a new Web browser tab, or just opening the same URL in the same tab may start a new session?

Session state is persisted as a cookie in the client-side (Web browser) and any tab or window within the same browser session (that would end if you close and re-open the browser) shares it. In other words: **all tabs or same browser session windows will share the same session state in the server-side**.

Comment: no same user name is shown in two different system after hiting the url

Comment: @Shipu So, you've confirmed that I'm describing your problem. Are you understanding it or you need any further detail about it?

Comment: unless you create a session variable with a different key i.e. one session per user. Coz otherwise a Session with the same identifier key would always get overwritten

Comment: @Amn yeah but check his first comment: **no same user name is shown in two different system after hiting the url** <-- it seems to be what I'm guessing that's his problem.

Comment: @Amn If the problem is "overwriting same session key" he should be finding that user name changes overtime...

Comment: Apologies, i think i got confused! a new session is created per browser so if you can create Session[<username>] = HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID and then use this Session everytime you want to see if the user is still authenticated, it should work, right? Coz effectively you are tying a particular Session to a particular user which will persist for all the calls from the same browser.

Comment: @Amn That's what I suspect :)